# TypeError: can't convert expression to float with Sympy

Tags: python, floating-point, typeerror, sympy

I'm trying to use sympy but am having trouble with its Symbol Objects.

```
import sympy as sy
from scipy import special as sp

def derivativeBMax2(s):    
x = sy.symbols('x', real=True)
B0 = 1 
H = 1
alpha = 2.4048 
B_azimuthal = B0 * H * sp.jv(1, alpha * sy.sqrt((float(x) ** 2) + (s ** 2)))
```

sp.jv from its documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.jv.html

requires a float for its second argument and when I convert x into a float it raises

```
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

I want to eventually differentiate B_azimuthal with sympy's diff()

How can I make x both a symbol and also a float for scipy's jv function?

Comment: What are B0, H, alpha, s? Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the post. They are both integers equal to 1.

Comment: Thanks. `alpha` and `s` are still undefined

Comment: Sorry about that! alpha is a defined constant and s is a free parameter in the function

Answer (score 0):

If scipy requires a float there is nothing you can do (other than replace the Symbol x with a float). If you want to work with it symbollically, why not just use SymPy's `besselj` function in `sympy/functions/special/bessel.py`. The docstring of that function gives examples of using symbolic arguments and does a differentiation, too.